# How can I know or define main Activity (AIR for Android)

Tags: android, flash, air, android-intent

How can I know or define main Activity of applications which is develop by AIR for Android, I have to use it for launching by Intent

like this

> Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER").setClassName("air.test.test.Test", "air.test.test.Test.Activity").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND).setComponent(new ComponentName("air.test.test.Test", "air.test.test.Test.Activity");
>      getContext().startActivity(launchIntent);

Answer (score 0):

just add the `intent filters` on your `activity` declaration tag on the `manifest` like this :

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```